# How to generate filtered report for records of all employees in table.in access

Tags: ms-access, macros, userform

I have a table and report generator form in ms access, my form has 3 combobox, 1 for start date , 2nd for end date and 3rd for employee name. So basically this form generates a report for the records, which has the given start date to the given end date from the "date" colum of the table for the given name of employee from the "AdvisorName" column of table, on click of a submit button. Here is the query i use in macro to generate and filter the report :

```
Mau_con![Action Date] Between DateValue(Forms!frmReportFilter!txtStartDate) And DateValue(Forms!frmReportFilter!txtEndDate) And Mau_con![AdvisorName]=Forms!frmReportFilter!cmbAdvNam
```

the combo box for name takes the values from a table, now I want this name combobox to have another option, "All", which should generate records of all the employees from the given start date to end date, instead of just pulling out reports for one employee.

I do not know the procedure for this neither I have any clue for the best query to drag the data.

Any help on this please.

Edit - if you feel I have not provided enough info or the question is not clear then please ask, marking down the question will revoke my access to ask further questions since i am a new user. Hence, request you guys to please atleast ask first else you will just stop my learning.

Edit 2(as table needed to answer the question) -

```
+-------------+-------------+
| Action Date | AdvisorName |
+-------------+-------------+
|             |             |
|             | Shiv Kumar  |
| 13/10/2017  | Adarsh      |
| 13/10/2017  | Varun       |
| 13/10/2017  | Shiv        |
| 13/10/2017  | Debbie      |
| 13/10/2017  | dasd        |
| 12/10/2017  | sdasd       |
| 13/10/2017  | Chesfeeda   |
| 13/10/2017  | Nishant     |
| 16/10/2017  | shiv        |
| 16/10/2017  | shiv        |
| 16/10/2017  | shiv kumar  |
| 16/10/2017  | asdas       |
| 16/10/2017  | shiv        |
| 16/10/2017  | shiv kumar  |
+-------------+-------------+
```

So this is my table name "Mau_con" I have total 14 columns in this, but as of now have nothing to do with others columns hence I have not pasted other columns

Comment: If you want us to help you form a query to pull certain data, most of the information in your question is irrelevant, and you should provide sample data, current attempt, current results and desired results

Comment: @YowE3K thanks for correcting one of my tags, apologies on that. And I am really using Macro here not access-vba. hope you would be able to help me with this question now  :)

Comment: @Erik von Asmuth Aplogies as its not possible to insert whole database or access table or form here, but I tried to provide most of the required info, but let me give the infor again, I have an access form with 3 combobox(2 to selecte the range from date colum like from 10/12/2017 to 12/12/2017, 1 is to choose the name of employee whose data needs to be extracted. My current attempt is `Mau_con![Action Date] Between DateValue(Forms!frmReportFilter!txtStartDate) And DateValue(Forms!frmReportFilter!txtEndDate) And Mau_con![AdvisorName]=Forms!frmReportFilter!cmbAdvNam` this query in macro builder

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth And that macro opens a report with where clause in which I am using the above mentioned query, which pulls data from seleted date range for the selected employees. My desired result is I want to add an option in employee name combobox for "ALL" which should pull reports for all employees from selected date range instead of just one employees, I do not know how to dos this, I hope I have provided you the required data hope you can help now.

Comment: @YowE3K that fine, but please be carefull buddy, you can end up revoking someone's access for nearly no reason, now I am not able to ask any further question on this website, And my project end date is coming near, thanks btw.

Comment: @shivchhabra You may not be able to share entire tables and databases, but you can share parts of tables. See [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359195/share-a-table-on-stack-overflow-for-easy-import-into-ms-access). Your question still seems a bit incomplete to me.

Comment: "you can end up revoking someone's access for nearly no reason" - I'm not sure what that means.  Edits to questions don't negatively affect the askers in any way.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Okay I was not aware we can do this as well, Lemme try that, if you really need table data, but how to include form ?

Comment: And I'm somewhat surprised that you have a question ban - you appear to have posted 5 questions, 2 of which have had an upvote, and this one having had a downvote.  I would have thought that that was pretty good and therefore you would have been able to continue asking new questions.

Comment: @shivchhabra you don't need to include the entire form, just list the relevant controls, and the relevant properties on those controls (e.g. for combo and list boxes, the row source is relevant if this question is about that combo/listbox). But really, it's just about the row source for a combo box, which is a query, so I'd say only the tables, current attempt, current output and expected output are relevant. Also see [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/7296893) (not all of that is applicable to Access).

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I have edited the question with table now, and My form has only three combobox(2 are to select the date range for data, 3 combo box is the list of employee name which has the row source from another table where I have saved the name of all emplyees) there is no VBA added to my form and and there is no control source since i am not saving data anywhere this form was created just to pull reports nothing more. and I just want to have an "All" option added to my employee name selection combo box which should pull reports for all employee names instead of one.

Comment: Ah, now I understand it better, and it really seems like June7 has the right idea. Did adding the _All_ using the union query work? In that case, you could just use an `OR` clause: `(all your criteria) OR Forms!frmReportFilter!cmbAdvNam = "All"`

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Yes Actually June7 has already answerd that in first go, but MArco builder does not allow more than 255 characters in Where clause, june7 suggested me to learn to solve this using VBA, so I am reading articles on that.

Comment: Like I said, you can shorten it a bit by using parentheses and `OR` instead of June7's solution. You can also try to work around that macro limitation by creating a tempvar and assigning your `WHERE` criterium to that tempvar. You can set a tempvar equal to itself + extra text if you need to work around limitations for that tempvar.

Answer (score 1):

Combobox RowSource will have to be a UNION query to add the "All" item. However, "All" is not a valid parameter for the report (unless actually have someone named All). Could use "*" as the choice for users in the combobox but this is not intuitive. So, change the report WHERE clause to:

`AND Mau_con![AdvisorName] LIKE IIf(Forms!frmReportFilter!cmbAdvNam = "All", "*", Forms!frmReportFilter!cmbAdvNam)`

Comment: thanks for the help, and sorry for late reply, Well I am not familiar with sql queries but after comibing my previous querry and the new one it comes out as `Mau_con![Action Date] Between DateValue(Forms!frmReportFilter!txtStartDate) And DateValue(Forms!frmReportFilter!txtEndDate) And Mau_con![AdvisorName]=Forms!frmReportFilter!cmbAdvNam AND Mau_con![AdvisorName] LIKE IIf(Forms!frmReportFilter!cmbAdvNam = "All", "*", Forms!frmReportFilter!cmbAdvNam) ` but the problem is I cant save this query in macros where clause as it says cant type more than 255 characters. what to do in this case

Comment: Maybe time to graduate to VBA. I don't use macros. http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: okay thats also a good idea, I will just check few links to learn how to do this in VBA, and then I will get back to u with my code. Thanks buddy :)

Comment: I tried the following vba on my command button, but its not working, can you help me with this : `Private Sub RprtBtn_Click()
    Dim MyCondition As String
    
    MyCondition =  [Action Date] Between #" & Me.[txtStartDate] & "# And #" & Me.[txtEndDate] & "#"
    DoCmd.OpenReport "MauConReport", , , MyCondition

End Sub` It gives sintax error

Comment: Need a quote mark in front of `[Action Date]` to start the string.

Comment: Okay I have done that,, but now on click of that button, it is giving print coomand for that report, what can be the possible issue

Comment: okay i got it, I chaned the view to report view, but the where condition did not work, it just showed me all the data.

Comment: Your dates are international style. That may be issue. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html. Otherwise, all I can say is the technique works for me.